# displaying a pdf with coldfusion from outside of the webroot

Tags: coldfusion

i don't know if this is possible, but with coldfusion could i display a pdf in the browser thats kept outside of the webroot?

so you can embed a pdf on a page like;

```
<object data="mypdf.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

could i do something like;

```
<object data="displaymypdf.cfm" type="application/pdf">
```

where displaymypdf.cfm would return that pdf? kinda like we do for downloads with cfheader/cfcontent?

thanks for any help/pointers

Comment: Yes, if `displaymypdf.cfm` contains cfcontent/cfheader tags returning the pdf binary as described below.

Answer (score 5):

In the CFHEADER tag, use the value: 'inline' and then use CFCONTENT. This should load the pdf into the browser.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=mypdf.pdf">
<cfcontent file="#yourDirectoryPathHere#mypdf.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

Comment: Just a note that you can use this for ANY type of file given the correct mime-type. Not just to load from outside the webroot, but to verify authenticated access to files as needed.